# Punchgs Slider Revolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, 3d

I've seen this very nice Javascript effect in `Slider Revolution`, where a `div` translates into a "3d" object and moves depending on where you hover.

Please have a look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAHRu.jpg). The left top img is in hovered state.

I wanted to apply that on my own html structure rather than in a slide so I've tried to copy the code and replace to variables etc. but I'm getting errors of undefined variables...

This was the orginial code:

```
var is_safari = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1);

var is_safari = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1);


revapi10.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
    var npe = document.getElementsByClassName("nopointerevent");
  for (var i=0;i<npe.length;i++) {
    npe[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    npe[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.zIndex = 100;
  }

jQuery('.ddd_mousebox').on('mousemove',function(e) {       
    var sto = revapi10.offset(),
        dim = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        tpos = jQuery(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode).position(),
        pos = {top:e.pageY-sto.top-tpos.top,left:e.pageX-tpos.aleft},
        perc = {wp:(pos.left/dim.width)-0.5, hp:(pos.top/dim.height)-0.5};
    getOverlaps(this);
    punchgs.TweenLite.to(this.overlapps,0.4,{force3D:"true",overwrite:"auto",transformOrigin:"50% 50% 100%", z:"300px",rotationY:0-((perc.wp)*5),rotationX:((perc.hp)*5),zIndex:30});
    punchgs.TweenLite.set(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,{zIndex:10});
    if (is_safari)
        punchgs.TweenLite.to(this,0.4,{force3D:"true",overwrite:"auto",z:"10px",transformOrigin:"50% 50%", rotationY:0-((perc.wp)*10),rotationX:((perc.hp)*10)});
    else
       punchgs.TweenLite.to(this,0.4,{force3D:"true",overwrite:"auto",z:"10px",transformOrigin:"50% 50%", rotationY:0-((perc.wp)*10),rotationX:((perc.hp)*10),boxShadow:"0 50px 100px rgba(15,20,40,0.35),0 20px 45px rgba(15,20,40,0.35)"});
});

jQuery('.ddd_mousebox').on('mouseleave',function(e) {
    punchgs.TweenLite.set(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,{zIndex:5});
    punchgs.TweenLite.to(this,0.5,{force3D:"true",overwrite:"auto",z:"0px",transformOrigin:"50% 50%", rotationY:0,rotationX:0,boxShadow:"0,0,0,0 rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
    punchgs.TweenLite.to(this.overlapps,0.5,{force3D:"true",z:"0px",overwrite:"auto",transformOrigin:"50% 50% 100%", rotationY:0,rotationX:0});
});

});

   function getOverlaps(el) {
    if (el.overlapps == undefined) {
      el.overlapps = [];
      var jel = jQuery(el),
      jpel = jQuery(el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode),
      pos_e = jpel.position();
      pos_e.bottom = jel.height()+pos_e.top;
      pos_e.right = jel.width()+pos_e.left;                                   

   revapi10.find('.tp-caption').each(function() {

   var cel = jQuery(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode),
       pos_cel = cel.position();                       

   if (this!==el && pos_cel.top>=pos_e.top && pos_cel.top<=pos_e.bottom && pos_cel.left>=pos_e.left && pos_cel.left<=pos_e.right)  el.overlapps.push(cel);
});

  } 
 }
```

Here's he fiddle where I tried to delete unnecessary stuff and replace variables like revapi10... What else do I have to take care of?

https://jsfiddle.net/30gd2pgc/

I would appreciate any help